# interval rails caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I need to cache a single page. I've used ActionController's caches_page for this. But now, I'd like to expire AND regenerate it once in every 10 minutes. What are my options?

later: I'd like to not use any external tools for this, like cron. The important point is **interval-based** expiry of the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [this](http://code.google.com/p/timedcachedfragment/) if you want to have fragments timeout.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK rails page caching compares the cache time on request and regenerates if necessary. If you need to forcibly flush that cache check out Sweepers.
http://www.railsenvy.com/2007/2/28/rails-caching-tutorial#sweepers